# Show warning on leaving without saving

Tags: reactjs

I'm working on a React page which has a card component which opens on clicking a button. I'm trying to show a warning if the user tries to close the card without saving the changes. The card doesn't have a close button, it closes when clicking anywhere on the screen outside of the card.

I've built a similar warning modal by checking if the route has changed, however since in this case the card component is part of the same page I cannot apply the same logic.

```
        <CardSidebar
            onHide={(e) => this.setState({ showSidebar: false})}
          >
            <FormComponent
              data={this.state.item}
              filterTypes={this.state.filterTypes}
              dataFields={stores.dataFieldStore.dataFieldsForDropDownComponents}
              refresh={this.refreshListHandler}
              cancelHandler={this.cancelHandler}
            />
            <>
              <RouteLeavingGuard
                // when={?}
              />
            </>
          </CardSidebar>
```

Answer (score 0):

So basically you want to know when the form is dirty and data is not saved so the guard would pop up. As far as I can see you are not using any library for handling this kind of behavior in forms so you need to build custom. I also don't see that you are using something as Redux so you need to lift state up and keep the isDirty value in the state of the component that is shown in the snippet.

```
//This code goes in the snippet that you pasted

 state={
   isDirty:false
 }

 isDirtyHandler(value){
   this.setState({isDirty:value})
 }
```

Pass the isDirtyHandler and isDirty as prop for check into the `<FormComponent/>` and inside the component make the following check

```
//This goes in <FormComponent/>

componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
if(this.state.data !== prevState.data && !this.props.isDirty) {
    this.props.isDirtyHandler(true)
}

onSubmitHandler(){
  this.props.isDirtyHandler(false)
  //whole logic for submitting the form
}
```

and just in the guard you are checking if form is dirty

```
<RouteLeavingGuard
  popUp={isDirty}            
/>
```